# Bilateral Filtering preserves the edge, but I want the opposite, an edge -bluring filter?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Is there such a filter that blurs the edge while preserves everything inside the bounding edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is one such filter! But if you want one you have to write one! Here is my Edge Smoothing algorithm! Hope you will find this useful!

```
bool SmoothEdge( Mat mInput_Bgr,Mat &mOutput_Bgr, double amount, double radius, byte Threshold) 
{
    if(mInput_Bgr.empty())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if(radius<1)
        radius=1;

    Mat mInput,mOutput;
    Mat mChannel[3];

    split(mInput_Bgr,mChannel);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        mInput= mChannel[i];
        SmoothEdgeSingleChannel(mInput,mOutput,amount, radius,Threshold); 
        mOutput.copyTo(mChannel[i]);
    }
    merge(mChannel,3,mOutput_Bgr);


    return true;
}

bool SmoothEdgeSingleChannel( Mat mInput,Mat &mOutput, double amount, double radius, byte Threshold) 
{
    if(mInput.empty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(radius<1)
        radius=1;

    Mat mGSmooth,mDiff,mAbsDiff;
    mOutput = Mat(mInput.size(),mInput.type());

    GaussianBlur(mInput,mGSmooth,Size(0,0),radius); 

    subtract(mGSmooth,mInput,mDiff);
    mDiff*=amount;
    threshold(abs(2* mDiff),mAbsDiff,Threshold,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    mDiff.setTo(Scalar(0),mAbsDiff);

    add(mInput,mDiff,mOutput);

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string FileName_S="Path\\Image.jpg";
    double m_Amount=1.5;
    double m_Radius=5.5;
    int m_Threshold=0;

    Mat mSource_Bgr,mSmoothEdge;
    mSource_Bgr= imread(FileName_S,1);

    SmoothEdge(mSource_Bgr,mSmoothEdge,m_Amount,m_Radius,m_Threshold);

    imshow("Source Image",mSource_Bgr);
    imshow("Output Image",mSmoothEdge); 
}
```

Here is my Results:
**Input Image**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: hi thank you for your effort! This is great! However it is such a pity I write python only... could you explain a bit about the theory of your filter so that maybe I can reproduce it on python?

Comment: @wudanao Failing to mention in the beginning that you would only accept Python code is not only counter-productive, it is exceedingly rude.

Comment: @wudanao The code is mostly calls to OpenCV functions, the translation to python should be quite straighforward. Nice solution!

Comment: @beaker

I dont think I ever said I would not accept the code? I just said I would want some theory on how this filter can blur the edge.

Comment: This is a very nice solution.  Straight forward.  However, it may help if you added some explanation of each processing step so that someone who isn't well versed in OpenCV could replicate the algorithm.